# Show terminal value

Tags: streamlit

I am able to plot data fine with

```
df = getDataFrame()['Change']
st.line_chart(df)
```

Is there a way to have the `line chart` show the terminal value on the right `y-axis` of `df`?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you currently have? And possibly of what you want. That would be of great help! ;)

Comment: Can you also share some sample data so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Well, I can show you what I want on a site. See how the terminal value is at the end of the line on the y-axis on the right? https://ycharts.com/companies/SPY/price#compCos=SLV,GLD&compInd=&format=indexed

Answer (score 0):

`st.line_chart()` is essentially a wrapper around `st.altair_chart()` with less customizability. To customize your chart more, you'll want to use `st.altair_chart`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61194028/adding-labels-at-end-of-line-chart-in-altair) explains how to add a label to an Altair chart for the point with the max x value. You can then pass your Altair chart with labels to `st.altair_chart`.

Comment: Thanks Caroline. This led me on the right path